# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Empty bindArgs

Tags: android, sqlite, sql-update

Sorry for bothering again, I am a Sqlite novice and need some help.

I am trying to update a single filed in a single row of a table .

I try to do this with:

```
db.getWritableDatabase().execSQL("UPDATE data SET korean = "
+kopulito+ " WHERE _id = " + constantsCursor.getString(0), null);
```

But I get the above mentioned error.
This is my LogCat.

```
05-05 09:58:07.776: E/AndroidRuntime(30495): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-05 09:58:07.776: E/AndroidRuntime(30495): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.koday/com.example.koday.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Empty bindArgs
05-05 09:58:07.776: E/AndroidRuntime(30495):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
05-05 09:58:07.776: E/AndroidRuntime(30495):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
05-05 09:58:07.776: E/AndroidRuntime(30495):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
05-05 09:58:07.776: E/AndroidRuntime(30495):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
05-05 09:58:07.776: E/AndroidRuntime(30495):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-05 09:58:07.776: E/AndroidRuntime(30495):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
05-05 09:58:07.776: E/AndroidRuntime(30495):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
05-05 09:58:07.776: E/AndroidRuntime(30495):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-05 09:58:07.776: E/AndroidRuntime(30495):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
05-05 09:58:07.776: E/AndroidRuntime(30495):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
05-05 09:58:07.776: E/AndroidRuntime(30495):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
05-05 09:58:07.776: E/AndroidRuntime(30495):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-05 09:58:07.776: E/AndroidRuntime(30495): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Empty bindArgs
05-05 09:58:07.776: E/AndroidRuntime(30495):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1793)
05-05 09:58:07.776: E/AndroidRuntime(30495):    at com.example.koday.MainActivity.updateall(MainActivity.java:301)
05-05 09:58:07.776: E/AndroidRuntime(30495):    at com.example.koday.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:72)
05-05 09:58:07.776: E/AndroidRuntime(30495):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
05-05 09:58:07.776: E/AndroidRuntime(30495):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
05-05 09:58:07.776: E/AndroidRuntime(30495):    ... 11 more
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: @NoobUnChained sorry but I do not know. How do I see that? I believe That is not in my code but in the Android code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `execSql` for updating the data.

Just remove the `null` parameter from the execSql command.

Comment: From documentation: `execSQL(String sql)` Execute a single SQL statement that is NOT a SELECT or any other SQL statement that returns data.

Answer (score 24):

this works for me: just remove null parameter from the execSql command

Answer (score 15):

Actually You CAN use `execSql` for updating data. Just remove **"null"** argument at the `execSql` method, so change this:

```
db.getWritableDatabase().execSQL("UPDATE data SET korean = " +kopulito+ " WHERE _id = " + constantsCursor.getString(0), null);
```

to

```
db.getWritableDatabase().execSQL("UPDATE data SET korean = " +kopulito+ " WHERE _id = " + constantsCursor.getString(0));
```

This works perfect.

Answer (score 1):

in my case i change this line

```
db.execSQL(query, null);
```

by this line

```
db.execSQL(query);
```

and it work.

Answer (score 0):

Method execSQL is overloaded. With execSQL(String SQL) you can do everything but can't return any data so it is usable for insert for example, it is perfectly possible I use it in my apps.

Answer (score 0):

I just change this:

```
db.execSQL("UPDATE cars SET fav = " + fav + " WHERE car_id = " + car_id , null);
```

by this:

```
db.execSQL("UPDATE cars SET fav = " + fav + " WHERE car_id = " + car_id);
```